# Why does $array -eq $null not evaluate to $true when $array contains only one $null element?

Tags: arrays, powershell, if-statement, null, comparison-operators

I'm finally taking the time to understand why Visual Studio Code nags me to [put `$null` on the left side of equality comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49411823/150605).

In playing around with this behavior, I found that when comparing an array containing `$null` elements to `$null` with `$null` on the right side, the "expected unexpected behavior" occurs with arrays containing two or more `$null` elements but not for arrays containing a single `$null` element.  That is, `if ($array -eq $null) { 'It equals $null!' }` outputs `It equals $null!` if `$array` contains multiple `$null` elements, but not when `$array` contains only one.  What is it about the number of `$null` elements that causes this discrepancy?

The following test code demonstrates this behavior...

```
function TestForNull($description, $value)
{
    $comparisonResult = $value -eq $null;
    $ifEntered = if ($value -eq $null) {
        $true;
    } else {
        $false;
    };

    Write-Host -Object $description;
    Write-Host -Object "`t`$comparisonResult.GetType(): $($comparisonResult.GetType())";
    Write-Host -Object "`t`$comparisonResult.Length: $($comparisonResult.Length)";
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $comparisonResult.Length; $i++)
    {
        $item = $comparisonResult.GetValue($i);
        $itemText = if ($null -eq $item) {
            '(null)';
        } else {
            $item.ToString();
        };

        Write-Host -Object "`t`$comparisonResult[$i]: $itemText";
    }
    Write-Host -Object "`t`$ifEntered: $ifEntered";
}

TestForNull '0-element array'                          @();
TestForNull '1-element array with all $nulls'          @($null);
TestForNull '2-element array with all $nulls'          @($null, $null);
TestForNull '3-element array with all $nulls'          @($null, $null, $null);
TestForNull '3-element array with one leading $null'   @($null, 2, 3);
TestForNull '3-element array with one inner $null'     @(1, $null, 3);
TestForNull '3-element array with one trailing $null'  @(1, 2, $null);
TestForNull '3-element array with two leading $nulls'  @($null, $null, 3);
TestForNull '3-element array with two boundary $nulls' @($null, 2, $null);
TestForNull '3-element array with two trailing $nulls' @(1, $null, $null);
```

...and outputs...

```
0-element array
        $comparisonResult.GetType(): System.Object[]
        $comparisonResult.Length: 0
        $ifEntered: False
1-element array with all $nulls
        $comparisonResult.GetType(): System.Object[]
        $comparisonResult.Length: 1
        $comparisonResult[0]: (null)
        $ifEntered: False
2-element array with all $nulls
        $comparisonResult.GetType(): System.Object[]
        $comparisonResult.Length: 2
        $comparisonResult[0]: (null)
        $comparisonResult[1]: (null)
        $ifEntered: True
3-element array with all $nulls
        $comparisonResult.GetType(): System.Object[]
        $comparisonResult.Length: 3
        $comparisonResult[0]: (null)
        $comparisonResult[1]: (null)
        $comparisonResult[2]: (null)
        $ifEntered: True
3-element array with one leading $null
        $comparisonResult.GetType(): System.Object[]
        $comparisonResult.Length: 1
        $comparisonResult[0]: (null)
        $ifEntered: False
3-element array with one inner $null
        $comparisonResult.GetType(): System.Object[]
        $comparisonResult.Length: 1
        $comparisonResult[0]: (null)
        $ifEntered: False
3-element array with one trailing $null
        $comparisonResult.GetType(): System.Object[]
        $comparisonResult.Length: 1
        $comparisonResult[0]: (null)
        $ifEntered: False
3-element array with two leading $nulls
        $comparisonResult.GetType(): System.Object[]
        $comparisonResult.Length: 2
        $comparisonResult[0]: (null)
        $comparisonResult[1]: (null)
        $ifEntered: True
3-element array with two boundary $nulls
        $comparisonResult.GetType(): System.Object[]
        $comparisonResult.Length: 2
        $comparisonResult[0]: (null)
        $comparisonResult[1]: (null)
        $ifEntered: True
3-element array with two trailing $nulls
        $comparisonResult.GetType(): System.Object[]
        $comparisonResult.Length: 2
        $comparisonResult[0]: (null)
        $comparisonResult[1]: (null)
        $ifEntered: True
```

Answer (score 2):

We already (hopefully) know that `$array -eq $null` evaluates not to a `[Boolean]` but to an array containing the elements of `$array` that are equal to `$null`.  As the condition of an `if` statement that resulting array must be converted to a `[Boolean]`, and though I could not find any official PowerShell documentation detailing the specifics of how that happens, it is the peculiarities of this conversion that are causing the behavior in question.  This is best illustrated not with `if` statements but simply with cast expressions...

```
PS> [Boolean] @()
False
PS> [Boolean] @($null)
False
PS> [Boolean] @($null, $null)
True
PS> [Boolean] @($null, $null, $null)
True
PS> [Boolean] @(New-Object -TypeName 'Object')
True
PS> [Boolean] @((New-Object -TypeName 'Object'), (New-Object -TypeName 'Object'))
True
PS> [Boolean] @($true)
True
PS> [Boolean] @($false)
False
PS> [Boolean] @($true, $true)
True
PS> [Boolean] @($true, $false)
True
PS> [Boolean] @($false, $true)
True
PS> [Boolean] @($false, $false)
True
PS> [Boolean] @(0)
False
PS> [Boolean] @(1)
True
PS> [Boolean] @(-1)
True
PS> [Boolean] @('')
False
PS> [Boolean] @('false')
True
PS> [Boolean] @('true')
True
PS> [Boolean] @('1')
True
PS> [Boolean] @('0')
True
PS> [Boolean] @('-1')
True
```

In case there's no discernible pattern there, the logic is...

1. Empty arrays are cast to `$false`.
2. Arrays with one element are cast to...

   - ...the length of that element as a `[Boolean]` if that element implements the [`IList` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist).
   - ...the result of casting that element to `[Boolean]` if that element does not implement the [`IList` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist).
3. Arrays with multiple elements are cast to `$true`.

Thus, given that `$array` contains one `$null` element (e.g. `$array = @($null)`), `$array -eq $null` returns `@($null)`.  When converting `@($null)` to a `[Boolean]` rule 2 above applies: `$null` casts to `$false`, therefore `@($null)` casts to `$false`.

Given that `$array` contains multiple `$null` elements (e.g. `$array = @($null, $null)`), `$array -eq $null` returns an array with the same number of (and, most importantly, multiple) `$null` elements.  The fact that `$null` casts to `$false` is irrelevant here because by rule 3 such arrays always cast to `$true`.

This is why it's significant whether an array contains one or multiple `$null` elements as far as the pitfall of performing a comparison with `$null` and passing the array as the first operand.

**Additional Reading:**

- `IsTrue()` method overloads of the [`System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives` class](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/56ad1d3a65122fcce6401efcbd3137ee4d2b1042/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/LanguagePrimitives.cs)
- [Why does the order of operands matter when testing for property of PSCustomObject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52154534/150605)
- [Comparison Operators, Collections, and Conditionals (Oh,
  My!)](https://powershell.org/2013/10/comparison-operators-collections-and-conditionals-oh-my/)
- [Casting Objects to Boolean in
  Powershell](http://blog.whatsupduck.net/2012/01/casting-objects-to-boolean-in.html)
- [Boolean Values and
  Operators](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators/)
- [PowerShell – Null comparison
  demystified](https://rencore.com/blog/powershell-null-comparison/)

Comment: @mklement0 I agree that this an exact duplicate (or pretty close to it) of [Why do PowerShell comparison operators not enumerate collections of size 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53107870/150605).  In looking for potential duplicates I had included "array", not "collection", in my search terms, which is probably why I did not come across that question.  It's interesting to me that so many of the pertinent questions on this matter are all from the last few months.